# Select <a> which is the second <a> on a page that contains the same href text? jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm working with a page that has several links that contain the same href text, and I need to select the second anchor element on the page that contains said href text. Here's a simplified version of the link structure of the page:

```
<a href="same/link/to/stuff/">same link</a>
<a href="same/link/to/stuff/">same link</a>
```

How do I fashion my selector so that it only selects the second anchor in the above example?

Currently I'm trying:

```
$('a[href=same/link/to/stuff/] :eq(1)')
```

but it is not working.

***Thanks!!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **Patrick Karcher** noted, you're missing a slash.

Also, you shouldn't have a space before `:eq(1)`.

```
$('a[href=same/link/to/stuff/]:eq(1)');
```

Spaces in selectors imply that the item after the space is a descendant of the item before the space.

The way you had it, you were attempting to select the second descendant element of `a[href=same/link/to/stuff/]`.

Comment: Ah it was the space!! Thanks so much!! May I ask why this makes a difference?

Comment: @Alex - Just updated my answer, but basically a space is essentially a descendant operator, so that jQuery looks for the item after the space which is a descendant of the item before the space.